# Paypal error in Dutch "De indeling van het bedrag van het object in de link waarmee u toegang heeft gekregen to het Paypal-systeem is onjuist"?

Tags: paypal

Does anybody know what this Dutch error means and how it translates to an English error message? The error is: `De indeling van het bedrag van het object in de link waarmee u toegang heeft gekregen to het Paypal-systeem is onjuist`.

It means something like "the layout of the amount of the object in the link that sent you to the Paypal system is incorrect"

Tried the whole setup and works fine in Sandbox, but in live situation I get this error.
I'm using the _xclick cmd, no shopping cart.

Comment: Can you show us some of your code? Is there anything else except that error message, like an error nr?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Free Translation](http://www.freetranslation.com/translate-english-dutch)

> The classification of the amount of the object in the link that lets
>   you access has been given to the Paypal system is incorrect

It sounds like the amount of your button is wrong. Did you specify a [currency_code](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/#id09A6G0U0GYK) as well?